# Eliminate two turtles in same patch

Tags: netlogo

Good afternoon everyone:
I am currently working in a Netlogo program that have three diferent types of turtles (tank, bullet, enemy). As you can imagine I want that when a bullet is in the same `patch` of a enemy both bullet and enemy `die`. The problem is that I don't know how to do it. I have tried with the following code, but it doesn't work because it eliminates when two enemies cross their patch and I only want to eliminate when a bullet and an enemy are in the same patch. I have also tried this code, which is also not working:

```
ask bullet [ if any? enemy-here [ die ] ]
ask enemy [ if any? bullet-here [ die ] ]



  to shoot
  if not mouse-down? or not mouse-inside? [ stop ]
     create-bullets 1 [
      setxy mouse-xcor mouse-ycor + 5
      set shape "line half"
      set color red
      set heading 360
      set size 4
    ]
end

to fire
  ask bullets [
    fd 0.006
    if pycor = max-pycor [ die ]
    **ask turtles with [count turtles-here >= 2] [ die]** ;this is the important part that why it is in strong
  ]
  tick
end

to move-tank
  setxy mouse-xcor mouse-ycor
  set hidden? not mouse-inside?
end
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

### Update following your reply in comment

Then the problem must be something else, because the code I gave you actually works and you can verify this yourself by using this little toy model I made:

```
breed [bullets bullet]
breed [enemies enemy]

to setup
  clear-all
  set-default-shape bullets "circle"
  
  create-enemies 30 [
   move-to one-of patches with [not any? enemies-here]
  ]
end

to fire   ; 'fire' is a button in the Interface.
  create-bullets 1 [
   move-to one-of patches with [not any? enemies-here]
   set size 0.5
  ]
end

to go
; I suggest to NOT make 'go' a forever-button, so to clearly see
; the moment in which the bullet hits an enemy and they both disappear.
  ask bullets [
   forward 1
   
   if (any? enemies-here) [
     ask one-of enemies-here [die]
     die
   ] 
  ]
end
```

You can see that when a bullet hits an enemy, they both disappear. Therefore, if applying this approach does not work in your model, the problem must either be (1) somewhere else in the model, or (2) in the way you adapted the approach to your case.

I am inclined to believe it is the second option, because the code unequivocally uses two `die` commands: one for the target enemy and one for the bullet itself, and no plausible way comes to my mind that could make any other part of a model interfere with this.

### Initial reply

First thing: check that the names of your breeds are correct. You said you have tanks, bullets and enemies, but in the code I see that you use `ask guns`. What is guns? Is it tanks, is it bullets, or is it none?

Anyway, the first thing you tried (the first two lines in the code you posted) doesn't work because you are asking a certain agent to perform a check (e.g. `if any? enemy-here`) and, if that condition is true, you are asking **that same agent** to `die`. Also, note that there are two syntax errors: no closing brackets at the end and you are using the singular version of your breeds to check for `<breeds>-here` (e.g. it should be `enemies-here` (or whatever you called them) instead of `enemy-here`).

In general, you should just do:

```
ask bullets [
 if (any? enemies-here) [
  ask one-of enemies-here [die]
  die
 ]
]
```

Note that this makes one bullet kill only one enemy, even if there are more enemies on that patch.

Comment: Thank you for your answer but it ocurrs the same. The enemy dies but the bullet continues alive.

Comment: @quik1399 Please check the update I made to the answer

Comment: I have seen that your code works. Thank you very much, I will revise my program following your indications. Let see if I can find the error.